# При генерации NavMesh в рантайме фризит игра

Tags: c#, unity3d

Моя игра бесконечная, значит я должен генерировать NavMesh постоянно в рантайме. Я написал это:

`_navMesh.UpdateNavMesh(_navMesh.navMeshData);`

И при каждой генерации игра замирает. Есть-ли возможность это пофиксить?

Слышал есть метод

`NavMeshBuilder.UpdateNavMeshDataAsync(data, GetBuildSettings(), sources, sourcesBounds);`

Однако не понимаю откуда брать последние 2 аргумента **sources** и ***sourcesBounds***

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.